# How to keep CDI context in an asynchronous event on Wildfly 11?

Tags: java, asynchronous, ejb, wildfly, cdi

We're developing on wildfly 11 and need to answer a rest call time-critical (below 300ms).
I already tuned the algorithm that calculates the result to answer below this threshold. But after I answered I want to trigger some preprocessing with the calculated result (create an object, store it in database).

This preprocessor injects services that are partly SessionScoped.

My first try was to trigger a javax.enterprise.event as soon as I calculated my response. That worked but it turns out that events are not asynchronous in CDI beans. So the rest call takes longer than necessary because it executes the post processor.

Now I followed the advice in [this](http://www.piotrnowicki.com/2013/05/asynchronous-cdi-events/) article and made the processing bean stateless and annotated the observer methods `@Asynchronous`.

The call is now triggered asynchronously but I'll lose the CDI context which I need in my preprocessor. Otherwise the injected services won't work.

I now that cdi 2.0 offers an fireAsync on Event but Wildfly 11 only contains cdi 1.2. So that is not an option.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work even for `fireAsync` until after the following CDI issues is resolved: propagate context to asynchronous calls. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-635

Comment: Oh. Okay. So we need to consider an architectural change at that point. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on when your transaction is commited, a solution would be to use @Observes(during = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMPLETION) ?

Comment: I already stumbled upon that option, but that doesn't help in my case because the event is not fired from a transaction.